# Coffeescript compile not correctly matching subdirectories

Tags: coffeescript

I have the root directory, /.  Inside of this, I have x/y.coffee.

Given the following command:

```
coffee -w -c -o ./ ./
```

I get this file as output: `./y.js`, without the directory.

If I have a subdirectory with more than two characters in its title, the javascript compiles to a subdirectory with the first two characters clipped.

This isn't entirely consistent for example, the `./gesture-panic/x.coffee` becomes `./nic/x.js`

Weird!

Comment: Does it work in `bash`? Also, in what way does "./y.js" not include a directory?

Comment: You're right, the cause was fish shell.

Comment: The shell performs [globbing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29) before your program executes.

Answer (score 0):

I have reason to believe this may be a fish shell issue.